# Commerce, different price based on quantity

Tags: 8, commerce

Is that even possible?

I read that Drupal 7 has some discount modules for that, but Drupal 8 doesn't have anything. Is that true? And maybe someone can point me in the right direction how to achieve this goal...

I have found this post: [Drupal Commerce - product attribute price based on quantity](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/189688/drupal-commerce-product-attribute-price-based-on-quantity) which suggests using https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_price_table module but nothing for Drupal 8.

Comment: It looks like you would need price lists, like in a B2B situation. See this module, which should have some sponsored work behind it soon https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_pricelist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a Promotion based on Product's quantity if that's what you're looking for. Just give a go to commerce_promotion module (included in Commerce 2.x core) and enable set conditions as on the picture below.

[image: promotion conditions]

Comment: Thanks. It does kinda work. It doesnt' change the price on the product page, and not even on the cart page, but adds a "discount" by substracting the amount difference. I'll live with that for now.

Answer (score 1):

Try the **Commerce Extended Quantity** module price adjustments for a current quantity in the cart: https://github.com/drugan/commerce_xquantity#quantity-price-adjustments